# Named geographic feature

Tags: google-maps

How can I get the name of my lake updated? The name was officially changed a while ago, but on Maps it still shows under the old name.

Here is the lake on google maps, it says Leech Lake but the real name is Porter Lake: https://www.google.ca/maps/@45.0080394,-79.6260121,17.5z

Comment: Right click on the lake, choose report a data problem, report the problem to Google.

Comment: @geocodezip, if it were that easy then I wouldn't be asking. When I right-click and try to report a data problem then (a) on Windows desktop it says "no results found near here" and (b) on iPhone it takes me over to a nearby road and suggests that I change the name of road. The inputs for roads don't let you say much about a lake.

Asking that if you are the person who -1'd then please put it back up.

Comment: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: You can still use the Send Feedback function by sending a screenshot of the page and writing your concern about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having issues when using the "Send Feedback" in the [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps), another way is to report a bug via [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/) of Google Maps Platform. For faster resolution, it is recommended that you share the full formatted address of the feature that should be corrected and the expected address for that feature, it would also be helpful if you include the Place ID of the location.

The Place ID of Leech Lake, Muskoka Lakes, ON P0E, Canada is: `ChIJhxqwN1DyKk0RHLCk0L6zda0`

You may also check the Place ID of other Places in the [Geocoder Tool](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/).

You may file the bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188871&template=788905). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, this sounds like a good answer, I will try it and come back here when I find out what happens.

Comment: Did it but I'm not getting an answer!! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137882004

Comment: Hi, if you file on a weekend then you will most likely to get a response on a Monday or Tuesday :)

Comment: @sjb-sjb, we've gone ahead and changed the lake's name to "Porter Lake"

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help !!  And Shawn, sorry I lost track of time there!